# Rolle's theorem with odd function

Tags: rolles-theorem

If I have some cubic equation $f(x)$, and I need to find how many solutions $f(x)$ has.
$f'(x)$ has two zeros, does it state that $f(x)$ has $3$ solutions by Rolle's theorem?

$$f(x)= x^3+2x^2-7x+1$$

Comment: Well, $p(x)=x(x+1)(x-1)+3$ has only one root but $p'(x)$ has two roots.

Comment: Rolle's Theorem only tells you for any pair of zeroes, there is (at least) one point in between where $f'=0$.

Comment: You should check whether the extrema, i.e. the points for which $f'(x)=0$ but $f''(x) \neq 0$, lie above or below the $x$-axis. $f(x)$ is not odd by the way.

Comment: For what domain of x?

Comment: You can check that $f(-\infty)<0$, $f(0)=1>0$, $f(1)=-3<0$, $f(+\infty)>0$ and $f(-\infty)<0$. Therefore, the intermediate value theorem tells you the existence of a root between each consecutive pair of those points.

Comment: @Paul  I can't use the theorem backwards? So if I have 2 point where f'=0 , then I have at least 3 point where f=0?

Comment: @VeronikaKovaleva Unfortunately, not. Consider $f(x) = 5 + \sin x$, this has an infinite amount of points with $f'(x)=0$ but no roots at all...

Answer (score 1):

If $f'(x )=0$ for $x=\alpha , \beta$ and $$f(\alpha) \cdot f(\beta) \le 0$$
Then $f(x)=0$ has three real roots.

Comment: If the two values are roots, then the function product of them must be zero. Where did the $<=$ come from?